# Spring Cloud Config failed to get the configuration from private git repository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

I was using the classpath of my spring cloud config server to put all the config files and now I decide to move it to a git server, so I created a empty repository and then commited my config files.

The config looks like this:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: server-config
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://development@xxx.xx.my.ip:/home/development/repository
          password: password
```

When I start the config server, everything works fine, but when I wont to access the configuration of a microservice through the url (example: http://localhost:8888/get-ticket/env) I get an following message:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback. Tue Sep 22 14:30:31 GMT-03:00 2015 There was an
>   unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Cannot load
>   environment

And in my stacktrace I can see:

> 2015-09-22 14:30:31.024  INFO 9160 --- [nio-8888-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 18 ms 2015-09-22
>   14:30:31.233 ERROR 9160 --- [nio-8888-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment] with root
>   cause
>
> org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException: URI not supported:
>   ssh:///development@xxx.xx.my.ip:/home/development/repository  at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:563)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:437)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:318)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.open(Transport.java:287)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:120)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)    at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.JGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:77)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spring config have an issue on ssh connection, use http instread

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud config gives you a 500 error when it tries to load a yml/properties file that has a synctatic error (e.g., duplicate key).

The error message gives you no useful information about the cause of the problem. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1283) to improve the error message.